# How to set spacing between columns in a UICollectionView with a vertical scrolling grid

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

I'm kinda new to `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` sophisticated topics, and yes!! I have checked all topic-related questions but still I'm stuck.

All I'm trying to achieve is to set spacing between **columns** in `UICollectionView` with a **vertical grid layout**.  And from all previous questions on the "how to set spacing on `UIcollectionViewCells`" topic, the primary answers that I have try'd unsuccessfully Are:

1. using `minimumInteritemSpacing` and `minimumLineSpacing`
2. using `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {`

the second solution for some reason did not achieve my goal 
  and the first solution is unhelpful in a **vertical grid layout** as the apple Docs instruct on the `collectionView(_:layout:minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt:)`:

*For a vertically scrolling grid, this value represents the minimum spacing between successive rows. For a horizontally scrolling grid, this value represents the minimum spacing between successive columns*

my question is: How could I do an easy workaround so that I could set spacing  between **columns** in a vertical `collectionView` , since  the exiting `minimumInteritemSpacing` and `minimumLineSpacing`  apply on columns only on a horizontal grid.

Comment: Do your cells have varying or constant widths?

Comment: @DonMag. do you mean the `sizeForItemAt indexPath` function?

Comment: No, I mean: Is each cell the same width? Such as - **every** cell is a 100x100 imageView? Or, might the first cell be a 100x100 image, the 2nd cell is a label that is 150-pts wide, the 3rd cell is a 60x60 image, etc?

Comment: @DonMag yes. I have set all cells in the `sizeForItem` func to the same `CGSize`. there is no difference in terms of size between the cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spacing between cells (columns) is determined by the width of the collectionView and the width of the cells and the "Minimum Spacing for Cells".

So, if your collectionView is 300-pts wide, and your cells are 100-pts wide, 3 cells * 100 == 300.

If your min-spacing is Zero, you will get 3 cells on each row with Zero  spacing.

If you set min-spacing to 40, 3 cells * 100 + (2 spaces * 40) == 380... which is too wide, so you will get only 2 cells on each row, and the space between will be 300 - (100 * 2) == 100.

So, to get a *specific, fixed space* between cells (columns), you need to calculate the total width needed and either change the width or the Section Insets of your collectionView.